# Is there any risk in using fetchColumn in PDO?

Tags: php, pdo

I often read notes, that this function is experimental. Is it true? What    consequences can be?

```
 $title_select_query_result = $title_select_query->fetchColumn(); 
  print("$title_select_query_result\n");
```

Comment: consequences? in what context? its vague what you're trying to do

Comment: @Ghost for example, in future updates / any bugs

Comment: Normally when something's marked as experimental it means that *how* it functions may be subject to future change - don't rely on the behavior as it is now to remain that way.

Comment: *see warnings* -- quote, please.